# How to coerce object parameters in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I've been playing around with the OCaml object system and typing in general. Recently I've been playing with polymorphic variants and objects and I've run into some trouble getting the type system to do what I want.

Here's what I've gotten to work, and makes sense

Given some type and function definitions:

```
type variant1 = [`Type1 | `Type2]
type variant2 = [`Type1 | `Type3]
type func1 = variant1 -> unit
type func2 = variant2 -> unit
let f1 : func1 = fun _ -> ()
let f2 : func2 = fun _ -> ()

(* Fails, but makes sense *)
let f3 : [`Type1] -> unit = f1
(* Error: This expression has type func1 = [ `Type1 | `Type2 ] -> unit
   but an expression was expected of type [ `Type1 ] -> unit
   The second variant type does not allow tag(s) `Type2 *)

(* Works, and is what I'd expect *)
let f3 : [`Type1] -> unit = (f1 : [`Type1] -> unit)
```

This makes sense so far, any function that can accept `Type1 + `Type2 should be able to be used where only `Type1 is needed. And this mostly works for objects:

```
type obj1 = < f : variant1 -> unit >
type obj2 = < f : variant2 -> unit >
type obj3 = < f : [`Type1] -> unit >
let o1 : obj1 = object method f = f1 end
let o2 : obj2 = object method f = f2 end
let o3 : obj3 = o1 (* Fails *)
let o3 : obj3 = (o1 :> obj3) (* Works *)
```

BUT, when the object type has method parameters that need to be coerced things fall over and I'm not sure how to convince the compiler to convert things:

```
type obj1 = < f : (variant1 -> unit) -> unit >
type obj2 = < f : ([`Type1] -> unit) -> unit >
let o1 : obj1 = object method f p = () end
let o2 : obj2 = (o1 :> obj2) (* Fails *)

Error: Type obj1 = < f : func1 -> unit > is not a subtype of
     obj2 = < f : ([ `Type1 ] -> unit) -> unit > 
   Type [ `Type1 ] -> unit is not a subtype of
     func1 = [ `Type1 | `Type2 ] -> unit 
   The second variant type does not allow tag(s) `Type2
```

To me it seems like it should still be valid to coerce obj1 types to obj2 types. Is this correct? Is this possible? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the subtyping relation goes in the opposite direction:

```
 let obj2 : obj2 = object method f p = p `Type1 end 
 let o3 = (o2 : obj2 :> obj1);;
```

because functions are contravariant with respect to their argument.

To understand why, consider for instance this specific value of type `obj1`:

```
 let o1 : obj1 = object method f p = p `Type1; p `Type2 end;;
```

If I could send a function that cannot handle `` `Type2 `` to `o1` it would fail. Thus, `obj1` is not a subtype of `obj2`. Contrarily, object of type `obj2` promises to only use the function argument on `` `Type1 ``, thus it is not problematic to use them as `obj1`, because they will always receive function argument that can handle more than `` `Type1 `` .

Comment: Ah! I understand now. Thank you!